# How to change collation of a linked server or collation of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

Is it possible to change a collation of a linked server?

I have to JOIN two tables. TableA is on a linked server with different collation then TableB which is on my local server. If it is not possible to change collation of an entire server maybe it could be possible to change the collation of Results based on TableA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the collation for the purposes of the join.  The syntax would be something like this:

```
Select *
From   TableA
       Inner Join TableB
         On TableA.StringColumn = TableB.StringColumn Collate Collation_Name_Here
```